# Python - server authenticate credentials / refresh token google (gmail) api

Tags: python-3.x, gmail-api

I have searched for an answer to this specifically but can't seem to find it. Apologies if it's a repeat.

I have sucessfully managed to send a gmail (to myself) via Python (3.6) using locally stored 'token.pickle' and 'credentials.json' files aS well as the code below which has been built from other searches and trial and error.

As is normal, the first time the code is run (no token exists), a browser window is launched and the user (me) is asked to verify access. Subsequently when the functions are run, the browser confirmation isn't necessary, because the code stores the access token locally for subsequent runs.

However, this is all locally from my laptop. What I want to do is have the program on a server, where even the initial browser confirmation is not necessary (because a browser can't be launched).

As part of this, I believe I have successfully set up my developer environment on google to have a redirect url to https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground and I've generated the access and exchange tokens.

However, I cannot find a simple explanation as to how to alter my currect locally run code, to use these other tokens etc, so that the browser confirmation at first runtime is not necessary, but authentication and the email being sent is still successful.

Here is the current code I run to send the email locally.

Please can someone tell me how I need to change it, to get the server hosted version to run as I am hoping? Thanks

```
def gmail_authenticate():
    creds = None
    # the file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time
    if os.path.exists("token.pickle"):
        with open("token.pickle", "rb") as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
            
    # if there are no (valid) credentials availablle, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
            
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            creds.refresh(Request())
            
        # save the credentials for the next run
        with open("token.pickle", "wb") as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
    return build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)


def send_email():
    service = gmail_authenticate()
    emailMsg = emailMsg
    mimeMessage = MIMEMultipart()
    mimeMessage['to'] = 'my email address'
    mimeMessage['subject'] = subject
    mimeMessage.attach(MIMEText(emailMsg, 'plain'))
    raw_string = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(mimeMessage.as_bytes()).decode()
    message = service.users().messages().send(userId='me', body={'raw': raw_string}).execute()
    
send_email()
```

Comment: Have you gone through [this guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server) in the official documentation? If so, what doubts do you have regarding it?

Comment: Hi @MateoRandwolf and thank you. Yes I've looked at that documentation and other documentation on google about its own API and how to do what I want to do. And while I can see that that particular documentation appears to be trying to explain how to do what I want to do, I don't understand it. It's beyond my level and I've read it, and re-read it countless times, and tried substituting parts of it in my code and I can't get it to work. To be honest, I find most of Google's own documentation is not written for someone at my current level, hence me asking here. Cheers.

Comment: Have you check [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server)? You can also consider [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account). If you need more help, it will be useful to have more information about your project. Which server are you using? Which is the purpose of the application?